# C++ main loop stutters occasionally

Tags: c++, windows, performance, time

I encountered a problem where my game-loop stuttered approximating once a second (variable intervals). A single frame then takes over 60ms whereas all others require less than 1ms.

After simplifying a lot I ended with the following program which reproduces the bug. It only measures the frame time and reports it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"

int main()
{
    unsigned long long frequency, tic, toc;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&tic);
    double deltaTime = 0.0;
    while( true )
    {
        //if(deltaTime > 0.01)
        std::cerr << deltaTime << std::endl;
        QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&toc);
        deltaTime = (toc - tic) / double(frequency);
        tic = toc;
        if(deltaTime < 0.01) deltaTime = 0.01;
    }
}
```

Again one frame in many is much slower than the others. Adding the `if` let the error vanish (cerr is never called then). My original problem didn't contain any cerr/cout. However, I consider this as a reproduction of the same error.

cerr is flushed in every iteration, so this is not what happens to create single slow frames. I know from a profiler (Very Sleepy) that the stream internally uses a lock/critical section, but this shouldn't change anything because the program is singlethreaded.

What causes single iterations to stall that much?

**Edit**: I did some more tests:

- Adding `std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(7) );` and therefore reducing the process CPU utilization does not change anything.
- With `printf("%f\n", deltaTime);` the problem vanishes (maybe because it doesn't use a mutex and memory allocation in contrast to the stream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of windows does not guarantee an upper limit on any execution time, since it dynamically allocates runtime resources to all programs using some logic - for example, the scheduler will allocate resources to a process with high priority, and starve out lower priority processes in some circumstances.   Programs are statistically more likely to - eventually - be affected by such things if they run tight loops and consume a lot of CPU resources.   Because - again eventually - the scheduler will temporarily boost the priority of programs that are being starved and/or reduce the priority of programs that are starving others (in your case, by running a tight loop).

Making the output to `std::cerr` conditional doesn't change the fact of this happening - it just changes the likelihood that it will happen in a specified time interval, because it changes how the program uses system resources in the loop, and therefore changes how it interacts with the system scheduler, policies, etc.

This sort of thing affects programs running in all non-realtime operating systems, although the precise impact depends on how each OS is implemented (e.g. scheduling strategies, other policies controlling access by programs to resources, etc).   There is always a non-zero probability (even if it is small) of such stalls occurring.

If you want absolute guarantees of no stalls on such things, you will need a realtime operating system.   These systems are designed to do things more predictably in a timing sense, but that comes with trade-offs, since it also requires your programs to be designed with the knowledge that they MUST complete execution of specified functions within specified time intervals.    Realtime operating systems use different strategies, but their enforcing timing of constraints can cause the program to malfunction if the program is not designed with such things in mind.

Comment: Adding `std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(7) );` reduces CPU utilization to 0.2%, but the stalling still occurs. It doesn't seem to be the tight loop which causes the problem.

Comment: CPU load is only one of the factors.  This really comes down to implementation of the system scheduler and scheduling policies (system wide settings that affect how the scheduler behaves) but doing things many times (e.g. in a loop) increases the likelihood of being affected eventually.   Sleeping is usually just another interaction with the scheduler (e.g. a thread/process yielding its timeslice) so doesn't eliminate the concern.   It just changes (hopefully reduces) frequency of occurrence, but elimination cannot be guaranteed without an RTOS.

Comment: I think you are right. Whatever causes this lag in scheduling, it is observable in all realtime applications on my system. I found that different commercial games and older projects of mine all show the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about it, but it could be that the system is interrupting your main thread to let others run, and since it takes some time (I remember on my Windows XP pc the quantum was 10ms), it will stall a frame.

This is very visible because it is a single-threaded application, if you use several thread they are usually dispatched on several cores of the processor (if available), and the stalls will still be here but less important (if you implemented your application logic right).

Edit: [here](http://recoverymonkey.org/2007/08/17/processor-scheduling-and-quanta-in-windows-and-a-bit-about-unixlinux/) you can have more information about windows and linux schedulers. Basically, windows use quantums (varying from a handful of milliseconds to 120 ms on Windows Server).

Edit 2: you can see a more detailed [explanation on the windows scheduler here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.02.vistakernel.aspx).